# dynamically allocating atwo dimensional array where each row contains variable number of elements & freeing it in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, multidimensional-array

How can I dynamically allocate a two dimensional array where each row contains variable element? How can I free this memory?

Comment: If the number of elements varies it's not actually a 2d array. It's an array of arrays. Yes, the distinction matters.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves: It is sometimes referred to as a jagged 2D array. The distinction is in the implementation not the usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you probably want a vector of vectors, something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vector_2d;
```

This way you'll benefit from the automatic memory management of the vector rather than having to manually manage the memory of an array of pointers to arrays of data.

Comment: You are absolutely right - I answered too quickly.  This will make it easier, but have a little more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You would need need to use pointers:

```
int ** a;
a = new (int*)[5];
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    a[i] = new int[x]; //where x is the size of this row
}
```

Something like this should work, but I didn't test it.

Comment: `a[i] = new int[ x[i] ];` would be better, if every row has different number of elements.

Comment: @zubrycki..whta does x[i] mean here?and how to free it?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    delete[] a[i];
}

Comment: and then `delete a`.  But the vector of vectors would be much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness:

```
int ** a;
a = new (int*)[5];

for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    a[i] = new int[x]; //where x is the size of this row
}

for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    delete[] a[i];
}

detete[] a;
```

Comment: boo hiss. I see new and delete. Don't like that :-(